# Can't run ionic cordova platform android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi everyone I am new on ionic v3 and I want to generate a new .apk. When I enter the command `ionic cordova platform android` I have this message:

> You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
>   Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Digit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk Requirements
>   check failed for JDK 1.8 JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>   cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use the command `ionic info` in your project folder and post the information? Also by the error message it seems that you don't have JAVA JDK configured in your enviroment variables, can you confirm that you have JAVA_HOME in it? Also, do you have Android SDK Manager installed?

Answer (score 4):

Your command `ionic cordova platform android` is not correct.

Instead, you must use `ionic cordova platform add android`.

Checkout [ionic cordova platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/platform/)